# create a database which can be seen only from one user

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to create a database in sql server 2008. But i want only one user can access in this database. Neither trusted_Connection neither Username in managment studio MyPcname and password WindowsAuthentication.

Also how secure is my database if someone will keep mdf files and open then in another computer which other login users have all rights.

This is my code for creating a database and a login user

```
 Create Database MyDb

 CREATE LOGIN [admin] WITH PASSWORD='1234', DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master], DEFAULT_LANGUAGE=[us_english], CHECK_EXPIRATION=OFF, CHECK_POLICY=OFF;ALTER LOGIN [admin] Enable;EXEC sys.sp_addsrvrolemember @loginame = N'admin', @rolename = N'sysadmin'
```

Also i dont want to be seen if someone will login with local

Comment: Plain and simple, this is not possible. Anybody with sysadmin can always view this database. As such they can also make a backup and move it elsewhere.

Comment: There is not way in local acess to prevent from viewing my database

Comment: No, as @Sean said, this is not possible. You cannot do what you're asking.

Comment: How about install a new SQL instance, only you can access, remove any other Administrators or BUILTIN\Administrators. And use database level encryption TDE.